# How to get default ProgressBar's drawable?

Tags: android, android-widget

ProgressBar's circle drawable differs from theme to theme. How can I get that drawable programmatically?
I have tried to do it this way

```
    Drawable progressDrawable = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.ProgressBar, 0, 0)
            .getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ProgressBar_progressDrawable);
```

But Gradle says that

> package com.android.internal.R does not exist

Comment: why do you need it ?

Comment: @Blackbelt because I need to show progress bar on my custom view. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048949/draw-progressbar-on-canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [R.styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#ProgressBar_progressDrawable) and [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#progressDrawable) documentation this should be accessible using

```
Drawable progressDrawable = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.ProgressBar, 0, 0)
            .getDrawable(android.R.styleable.ProgressBar_progressDrawable);
```

Comment: `com.android` doesn't exist, nor does `android.internal`.